# How to get column to equals according in database

Tags: java, jframe

I got problem with this on IFELSE statement
what i should i do? for equals of my position to database ACCESS
. I want to do is if the Admin is correct they show the CP and Staff is correct they show the AS for getting on position to my database.

```
addStudents AS = new addStudents();
ControlPanel CP = new ControlPanel();

try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:slcvJavaEnrollment");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st
            .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM loginUsers where Username='"
                    + userTxt.getText() + "' and Password='"
                    + passTxt.getText() + "'");

    if (rs.getString("Position").contentEquals("Admin")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME ADMIN");
        CP.show();
        dispose();
        con.close();
        st.close();
    } else if (rs.getString("Postion").contentEquals("Staff")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME STAFF");
        AS.show();
        dispose();
        con.close();
        st.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: just suggestion : please read about sql injection as you are not using parametrized query.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @peeskillet My question is how to get correctly to my Column name is Postion . how i get there position by according where they got show.

Comment: @Learning Why not using parametrized? If statement not work without that.

Comment: @user3144438, I was giving you the suggestion, btw the spelling of Position is wrong, that may be reason.

Comment: I think @Learning was suggesting you use a `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @peeskillet, yup you are correct, I was taking about `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Learning
peeskillet

Not Resultset for select?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `while (rs.next())` to move the result set to the next result. Try this out. Also as @Learing pointed out, you spelled "Position" wrong in your `else if`.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString("Position").contentEquals("Admin")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME ADMIN");
        CP.show();
        dispose();
        con.close();
        st.close();
    } else if (rs.getString("Position").contentEquals("Staff")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME STAFF");
        AS.show();
        dispose();
        con.close();
        st.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To prevent SQL injection, you should use a PreparedStatment.

Try this instead of what you have

```
PreparedStatment pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from loginUsers WHERE Username=? and Password=?");
pstmt.setString(1, userTxt.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, passTxt.getText());

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: For the elseif statement
i got error 
NO DATA Found

but i got on my database and i create new users for staff but no data found :(

Comment: Did you fix the spelling?

Comment: yeah all of spelling every letter i got correct triple check! but on elseIf they got no Data found

Comment: Try to use my code in my **Edit** using a prepared statement.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Username=Pa_RaM000and Password=Pa_RaM001'

That the error.. i dont know what i should do

Comment: It's missing a space before the `and`

Comment: They correct but on elseif statment i got a problem to the NO DATA FOUND !!

Comment: Then there's probably no data found.

Comment: but on my database have many staff accounts only staff can't recognice on PS

Comment: It didn't work before you used the preparedstatement, so it has nothing to do with that